# Deploying on Wildfly using jboss-as-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm actually really new to this...
everytime I try to deploy a war file in Wildfly it gives me this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.774 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-23T01:56:20+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/283M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.3.Fi
nal:deploy (default-cli) on project jbpm6-example: Could not execute goal deploy
 on E:\Apps\jbpm6-example\target\jbpm6-example-1.0.war. Reason: Error could not
execute operation '{
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }'. java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote:/
/localhost:9999. The connection timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

I've tried configuring the plugin in pom.xml like this to connect to port 9999 since from what I've searched wildfly is using port 9990..

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.Final</version>

    <configuration>  
     <hostname>localhost</hostname>  
     <port>9999</port>
    </configuration>  

  </plugin>
```

but still can't deploy it...

I've also tried using the wildfly-maven-plugin but it also gives me an error: Deployment failed and was rolled back

Answer (score 0):

Older `jboss-as-maven-plugin` will not work with WildFly. You need to use the newer `wildfly-maven-plugin` only. It can be defined as:

`<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
        ...
    </build>
...
</project>`

And then `mvn wildfly:deploy` will work.

Here is a blog that provide more details:

http://blog.arungupta.me/wildfly-maven-plugin-tech-tip-9/

All Java EE 7 samples at https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples use this plugin as well.

Alternatively, you can find a simpler Java EE 7 sample using this plugin at:

https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-simple-sample/blob/master/pom.xml